# I have a dataframe called df1 and I want to save only the 'CSDA' book titles to a file called csdatext.csv. How can I do that?

Tags: python

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('master_textbook_list_for_connections.xlsx')
df1.head(5)
df1.columns
new_df = df1.to_csv("csdatext.csv", index=False, columns=['PREFIX'='CSDA'])
```

** I have created a data frame and I need to save only the part where prefix = 'CSDA' called csdatext.csv**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming "Prefix" is a column here:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('master_textbook_list_for_connections.xlsx')
df1.head(5)
df1.columns
new_df = df1[df1['PREFIX'] == 'CSDA']

new_df.to_csv("csdatext.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Yes. PREFIX is the column and I want to save the book titled only 'CSDA'  in csdatext.csv

Comment: The code i posted should do the job then. Have you tried it?

Comment: I would appreciate if you could provide me with the link to that code.